# Overlay overrules images - Can't automate src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image that uses jquery for when an image is clicked, this will return the image src for that image. I modified my HTML/CSS to give this image an overlay.

However, I have now added an overlay that comes from left to right when the image is hovered. This added complications, as now when the jquery tries to find the image src, it can't because the overlay is covering it.

This has meant I have to manually write the code for each image src, but this does not work because obviously when you click each image, each one will have a different img src.

To provide example:

```
$(".dogs img").click(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
    });
```

Now that I have an overlay, unless I'm really fast and beat the overlay covering my screen, I can't click the image, but only the overlay covering it.

```
<div class = "cover-overlay">
     <img src = "dog-1.png">
</div>

<div class = "cover-overlay">
     <img src = "dog-2.png">
</div>

<div class = "cover-overlay">
     <img src = "dog-3.png">
</div>
```

So now I have to do,

```
$(".dogs .cover-overlay").click(function(){
        var src = $(".dogs img").attr("src");
}
```

however this will obviously always return the source of the first image in dog class, because of how the click function now works with overlay. Any suggestions?

Comment: add $(this) here: var src = $(".dogs img", $(this)).attr("src");

Answer (score 3):

You can still use `this` to reference the clicked `.cover-overlay` element, but now you need to also use `find()` to get the child `img` from it:

```
$(".dogs .cover-overlay").click(function(){
  var src = $(this).find('img').prop("src");
});
```